# Не работает css js

Tags: javascript

js

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 0;
    $("#addrow").on("click", function () {
        counter = $('#myTable div').length - 2;
        var select = "";
        select += '<select class="form-control js-example-basic-single" name="name'+counter+'">';
        select += '<option><?=Yii::t('main','text_select_values')?></option>';
        select += '<?php foreach ($products as $product):?>';
        select += '<option value="<?=$product->product_id?>">';
        select += '<?=$product->name?>';
        select += '</option>';
        select += '<?php endforeach; ?>';
        select += '</select>';


        var newRow = $("<div>");
        var cols = "";
        cols += '<abbr><div class="row">';
        cols += '<div class="col-md-6"><div class="input-group select">'+select+'</div></div>';
        cols += '<div class="col-md-2"><div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity' + counter + '"/></div></div>';
        cols += '<div class="col-md-2"><div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="price' + counter + '"/></div></div>';
        cols += '<div class="col-md-1"><div class="input-group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-icon ibtnDel"><span class="icon-minus-circle2"></span></button></div></div>';
        cols += '</div></abbr>';
        newRow.append(cols);
        //if (counter == 4) $('#addrow').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "You've reached the limit");
        $("div.order-list").append(newRow);
        counter++;
    }); 
});
```

Подключил скрипты 
     $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();

По идеи

```
    select += '<select class="form-control js-example-basic-single" name="name'+counter+'">';
```

Это должно работает поиск по выпадающему списку вот отсюда взял `Select2 https://select2.org/` 
если в вставить в html то все работает, но почему то не работает если написать это в js, может объяснить почему так не работает ?

Comment: это не html, вот и не вставляется

Comment: Но другие классы работают например `form-control` почему не работает  `js-example-basic-single`

Comment: Как в браузере должен выполниться php код по вашему?

Comment: не код выполняется, появляется выпадающий список, но не срабатывает, js, css   `js-example-basic-single` который осуществляет поиск по списку

Comment: Мне еще раз свое первое сообщение повторить? Вы вставляете php код прямо на страницу

Comment: Хорошо а можно как то сделать что бы был поиск по выпадающему списку

Comment: В примере кода нет никакого поиска, Вы просто добавляете на страницу выпадающий список, Вам это и надо?

Comment: Для этого надо сначала получить с сервера $products в виде Json

Comment: Все понял спасибо

Comment: нет проблем, обращайтесь